# Is the definition of DTFT using $\omega$ wrong?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'll briefly explain this problem I faced.

Let's take this simple signal:
$$x(n)=\cos(\pi n)$$
The signal is not absolutely summable, however we can define its DTFT in terms of distributions. That is:
$$X(e^{j\omega})=2\pi \delta(\omega+\pi+2\pi k)$$
Note that the impulse has amplitude equals $2\pi$.

Now, let's take this signal:
\begin{equation}
y(n)=
\begin{cases}1 &n=0\\-1 &n=1\\0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and compute the DTFT of this signal according to this definition:
$$X(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(n)e^{-j\omega n}$$
We obtain:
$$Y(e^{j\omega})=1-e^{-j\omega}$$
Computation of the DFT of the signal returns:
$$Y[0]=0\qquad Y[1]=2$$
so, ok, DFT is the sampled version of the DTFT because $Y(e^{j\omega})$ evaluated in $\omega=0$ and $\omega=\pi$ turns out to be exactly the values calculated from the DFT.

Anyway, how can I explain the amplification by $2\pi$ in $X(e^{j\omega})$?
Note that using the following definition of DTFT the problem doesn't appear:
$$X(e^{j2\pi f})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(n)e^{-j2\pi f}$$
because the transform of $x(n)$ in terms of distributions is:
$$
X(e^{j2\pi f})=\delta(f+0.5+k)
$$
which has amplitude 1.
Moreover:
$Y(e^{j2\pi f})=1-e^{-j2\pi f}$.

So, is the definition of DTFT using $\omega$ wrong?